# How to implement a websocket client using twisted?

Tags: python, websocket, twisted

Is there any documentation on how to implement a websocket client using twisted? Alternatively, does anybody have experience with something like this and could help me getting started?

Comment: What do you mean by "websocket client using twisted"? Twisted is a server framework. For a websocket client in Python just google it.

Comment: Maybe you can use try https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client.  If you just want to test connect to a web socket server, you can just use something simple like curl, ex: https://gist.github.com/htp/fbce19069187ec1cc486b594104f01d0

Comment: Also take a look at https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/tree/master/examples/twisted/websocket. The echo example is short and sweet.

Comment: Twisted is not a server framework.  Also this question falls short of many of the SO requirements for questions.  Voted to close.

Comment: @stx101 Is right go with Autobahn.